# Hacer referencia componente agm-map Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

Como podría hacer referencia al componente agm-map como si fuese un div cualquiera en angular?

Estoy utilizando la api de google maps, lo estoy implantando en angular y tengo muchos problemas y cuando busco soluciones, todos hacen referencia al mapa de google maps de forma externa a angular, creando un 
*new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});*
 y de tal manera, puede hacer un setZoom(16) y automáticamente le funciona; bien, ahora yo hago referencia mediante un id y siguiendo el manual (*https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap*) de mapas de angular intento utilizar la propiedad zoom: this.mapa.zoom = 16 y no funciona, así como con otras propiedades más.

Estoy entendiendo algo mal, o es que agm-map esta más limitado que el mapa de forma externa?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza su selector: `<agm-map></agm-map>`.Para personalizar el mapa utiliza los atributos del selector: `<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-map>` donde `lat` y `lng` son propiedades que tienes en el controlador.
Tienes todos los atributos o inputs que puedes utilizar aqui: https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap